# Async ajax sometimes not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

Asynchronous ajax requests doesn't work about 90% of the time in Firefox. 10% of the time it works (under seemingly same conditions). It does work in Chrome 100% of the time. Also if I detect the browser and use async: false for Firefox it works 100% of the time.
I error_log on the first line of the php page that the ajax refers to. It doesn't show up in the log. Also there is no error in the console and the ajax error function is not executed. Below is an example that works if it includes the check for the browser but doesn't otherwise.

```
function myAjax(data) {
  console.log("called");
  isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'confirm.php',
    async: !isFirefox,
    data:{action:'call_this', data: data},
    success:function(html) {
      alert(html);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }}
  });
  window.open("index.php","_self");
}
```

edit:
function is called when a button is pressed, "data" is a string.

```
<button id="confirm" onclick='myAjax("<?php  echo $data; ?>")'>Confirm </button>
```

no "POST" request shows up in the firefox network tab

Comment: You should avoid using **async: false** as it is being deprecated not only by jQuery, but by browsers themselves.  You need to think in an asynchronous pattern.

Comment: If you look in the 'Network' tab in the Firefox Dev Tools, do you see the request come in? Does it error out?

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy ?

Comment: `Asynchronous ajax requests doesn't work about 90% of the time in Firefox` Async requests work 100% of the time in Firefox when used correctly. Your time would be better spent trying to debug any issues you have with the request instead of trying to hack around a sync solution. The first thing to debug is what value `data` holds and where this function is called from

Comment: @Jan I don't see any request with Method "POST" in the network tab.I agree that this should be done in an async way.